# Nextflow Error: Not a valid S3 file system provider file attribute view: java.nio.file.attribute.BasicWithKeyFileAttributeView

Tags: java, amazon-s3, bioinformatics, nextflow

I'm encountering an error while running a Nextflow process. The specific error message is related to the S3 file system provider and the file attribute view. I'm trying to run a sample dataset with the following parameters.

`nextflow run nf-core/scrnaseq -r dev -input https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nf-core/test-datasets/scrnaseq/samplesheet-2-0.csv --outdir ./results --genome GRCh37.`

```
[b0/8284b8] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:INPUT_CHECK:SAMPLESHEET_CHECK (samplesheet-2-0.csv) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✔
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:FASTQC_CHECK:FASTQC                                 -
[4e/588c5d] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:GTF_GENE_FILTER (genome.fa)                         [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✔
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ_ALEVIN:SIMPLEAF_INDEX                      -
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ_ALEVIN:SIMPLEAF_QUANT                      -
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ_ALEVIN:ALEVINQC                            -
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:MTX_CONVERSION:MTX_TO_H5AD                          -
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:MTX_CONVERSION:CONCAT_H5AD                          -
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:MTX_CONVERSION:MTX_TO_SEURAT                        -
[-        ] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:CUSTOM_DUMPSOFTWAREVERSIONS                         -
[82/3a47a6] process > NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:MULTIQC                                             [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'NFCORE_SCRNASEQ:SCRNASEQ:MULTIQC'

Caused by:
  Not a valid S3 file system provider file attribute view: java.nio.file.attribute.BasicWithKeyFileAttributeView


 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details


-[nf-core/scrnaseq] Pipeline completed with errors-
```

I am trying to run the Nextflow pipeline in the Sagemaker Jupyter Notebook Instance and running its processes in the AWS Batch jobs.

Nextflow version: 23.10.0
Java version: 21.0.1

Comment: Only thing I can think of here is that the file names contains colon which are outside of S3 list of safe characters and needs to be handled in a special way: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html maybe nextflow (which im not familiar with) uses the same rules for file names